# UIImagePickerController with ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to get images from photo library but I have a problem.I have 3 different ImageViews. And 3 different tap gestures on those Imageviews. I need to choose different photos and show them to the users.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

- Add `UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` to your Controller
- The function to create UITapGesture

  ```
  func createTapGesture(selectorName: String) -> UITapGestureRecognizer {

      return UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(selectorName))
  }

  func imageTap(sender: AnyObject) {

      currentImageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
      pickImage()
  }
  ```
- Show ImagePickerView

  ```
  func pickImage() {

      let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
      imagePicker.delegate = self
      imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
      imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
      self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

      dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
      currentImageView.image = image
  }
  ```
- Add these codes to viewDidLoad

  ```
  firstImageView.addGestureRecognizer(createTapGesture("imageTap:"))
  secondImageView.addGestureRecognizer(createTapGesture("imageTap:"))
  thirdImageView.addGestureRecognizer(createTapGesture("imageTap:"))
  ```
- In IB, make sure your images view set `User Interaction Enabled` checked

Hope this can help

Comment: thanks for reply.How can I define currentImageView can you help

Comment: currentImageView is an UIImageView you can define in global. so that you can use it anywhere.